# How do I wait for an element using the WinAppDriver in UWP?

Tags: selenium, uwp, appium, coded-ui-tests, winappdriver

I'm currently migrating my Coded UI Tests for a UWP app to Appium using the [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) and I have come across the issue, that I can't wait for an element to show up. There is no way to wait for a element to be "ready" as the Coded UI Test from Microsoft did.

In the `ClassInitialize` method everything works fine (data is entered on the login view) and the login button is clicked. After the click event is triggered the app shows a progress bar until the user is logged in. My problem is that I cannot wait for the components after the login process.

I have found some code snippets, however, they don't seem to work for me. Here is the extension method I'm currently using:

```
public static IWebElement WaitForElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
   if (timeoutInSeconds > 0){
      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
      var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
      return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
   }
   return driver.FindElement(by);
}
```

I have also read that the implicit timeout for the Windows driver has to be set:

```
session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);
session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

and overridden in the `WaitForElement` method, which also didn't work for me.

[Waiting for element before clicking with WinAppDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56117645/waiting-for-element-before-clicking-with-winappdriver)

```
[TestMethod]
public void UploadDocuments()
{
   var UploadButton = session.WaitForElement(By.XPath("//Button[@AutomationId='AddDocument']"), 60);
   UploadButton.Click();

   session.FindElementByXPath("//ToolbarWindow32[@AutomationId='1001']").SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
   session.FindElementByXPath("//ToolbarWindow32[@AutomationId='1001']").SendKeys(testFilesFolder);

   //session.FindElementByName("Open").Click();
}
```

The test usually crashes in the first line after it's finished with the `ClassInitialize`. So I would like to wait for the 'AddDocument' button to pop up before the test carries on.

If anyone has a solution I'd appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement wait funcionalities like this:

```
public WindowsElement GetElementByAutomationID(string automationId, int timeOut = 10000)
{
    WindowsElement element = null;

    var wait = new DefaultWait<WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>>(Driver)
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeOut),
        Message = $"Element with automationId \"{automationId}\" not found."
    };

    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverException));

    try
    {
        wait.Until(Driver =>
        {
            element = Driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId(automationId);
            return element != null;
        });
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex)
    {
        LogSearchError(ex, automationId);
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }

    return element;
}
```

Your problem seems to be a appium-dotnet-driver issue.
See these issues on github about this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/329

https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/issues/225

Comment: The answer did not work at this time. If you change `wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverException));` to `wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(InvalidOperationException));` your wait timeout will function again. Reason is, that when calling `FindElementByAccessibilityId` you'll get `InvalidOperationException` fired when element is not found and **NOT** `WebDriverException`.

Comment: @krs thx for this update. All I know is that it used to work at the time of writing that answer.
- Doing a assumption here - perhaps this was changed in more recent versions of the selenium framework?

Comment: @PixelPlex For me, when using either exception type - WebDriverException or InvalidOperationException, the function immediately returns the error "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters" and doesn't wait for the timeout